# Matching contents of a String with a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I am struggling a bit to create a regex matching pattern to be used with matches() method of String.
My String value is something like -

```
3012145A_20348409-146139460.ABCDxyzPQr.1.1.xml
```

I am using the String.matches("regex") method but to be honest struggling to create the pattern which will match the String values like these.
I did try a few different combos but in vain so for. Searched on the internet for some examples.
The values are always going to be in similar format though the length might vary.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

There is more to matching just .xml
Well, apart from the example given there will be other values too in the List, so I need to match like

```
3012145A_20348409-146139460.ABCDxyzPQr.1.1.xml
```

The list of values could be like -

```
3012145A_20348409-146139460.ABCDxyzPQr.1.1.xml
3012145_Error.xml
3012145_UK.pdf
3012145A_20348409.ABC.10.10.10.xml
```

I need the first value among these

```
(alphanum)(underscore)(num)(hyphen)(num)(dot)(aLpHa)(dot)(num)(dot)(num)(dot)(.xml)
```

I tried this -

```
s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]_[0-9]-[0-9].[a-zA-Z].[0-9].[0-9].xml");
```

Comment: what are you trying to match, i.e. what are the rules? anything ending with ".xml" or is there more to it?

Comment: I agree. Before expressing your regex, you should be aware of the formal definition of your string. This will match: `\w+_\d+-\d+\.\w+\.\d\.\d\.xml`. But this also `.*?\.xml`. And many more things...

Comment: You should add few more examples of what you want to match and what should not match.

Comment: `(dot)(.xml)` converts to regex `\.\.xml`, which matches `..xml`.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Requirement :**

`(alphanum)(underscore)(num)(hyphen)(num)(dot)(aLpHa)(dot)(num)(dot)(num)(dot)(.xml)`

**Supposed regex:**

`\w*_\d*-\d*\.([a-zA-Z])*\.\d*\.\d*(\.)?\.xml`

In java this will translate to:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*_\\d*-\\d*\\.([a-zA-Z])*\\.\\d*\\.\\d*(\\.)?\\.xml",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

**Note**

As I am using `[a-zA-Z]`, you might not need `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`

Problem with your regex: `s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]_[0-9]-[0-9].[a-zA-Z].[0-9].[0-9].xml");`

You are looking for a single instance of either `alpha`, `number` or `alphanumeric`. Use `*` or `+` metacharacters.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant!. Thanks a lot Favonius.
That worked perfectly.
So as I understand that what I was doing is even though I was giving a range `[0-9a-zA-Z]` it was actually trying to match only the first char, in my example, `3`.
So in reality rather than `3012145A` it was checking only whether `3` is part of my given range(`[0-9a-zA-Z]`) and so forth for the entire String.
Your solution `\w*` will check whether that particular section is alphanumeric or `\d*` will check whether the section(bounded by the boundaries, say `.` or `_`) is within the whole range of numbers and/or alphabets.

So a very murkier way of matching `3012145A_` could be

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]_
```

I am not proposing this solution just trying to understand the behavior and difference between `[0-9]` and `\d*`.

I still have a question though, the significance of `(\\.)?\\.`, whats the purpose of this.

Thanks a lot again

Comment: I think the `(\\.)?\\.` is there because of an error in your spec.  See my comment under the question for details.

Comment: Alrite, if I dont include (\\.)?\\. in my regex, its still fine. I mean obviously for my spec which ends with (num)(dot)(xml) or (num)(.xml). Still, I would like to know what it signifies. As, I believe it translates to .?., so is the ? like for any single char

Comment: @user538058: `(\\.)?\\.` it signifies **zero** or **single** occurrence of **DOT** followed by a **DOT**. And as Alan mentioned it was because of your spec. So instead of using `(\\.)?\\.`, you can have `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*_\\d*-\\d*\\.([a-zA-Z])*\\.\\d*\\.\\d*\\.xml",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` :)

Comment: @user538058: Yes it is a very murkier way of matching 3012145A_ using `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]_`. The `\d` is a short hand for `[0-9]`. `\d*` means zero or more occurrence of digits. Go through some regular expression tutorial for more details.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot for all the explanations.

Comment: @user538058: Welcome :). If the answers solved your problem then please mark it accepted that way it will be out of unanswered list. thanks.